# Tracking outgoing RestTemplate/Feign requests in JProfiler

Tags: resttemplate, jprofiler

when using JProfiler I'd like to be able to see outgoing RestTemplate requests in the calltree/hot spots of CPU views in the similar way JDBC/JPA/Mongo queries are shown and aggregated.

Is there some kind of configuration/scripting/extension to achieve this goal?

Right now when monitoring microservices that make a lot of REST calls it is hard to understand where is the time spent - locally or waiting for answer and to which endopoint.

Thanks

LZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is currently under development and will be available in JProfiler 11.0.